# Flask - calling the backend API gets different session ID every call

Tags: reactjs, docker, flask, session, single-sign-on

I'm using a pretty standard combo Flask + React to develop a web app. Recently I needed to implement a Google SSO auth - which I did. The auth flow is pretty standard - from the frontend app (React), I'm calling the `/sso/login` endpoint, which initializes the OAuth2 client, generates the authorization URL and redirects the call to said URL. After logging in to the Google, the user gets redirected to `/sso/auth`, which gets the auth tokens, and in this endpoint (this is important) I'm retrieving the user details, which I save to the session (using Flask-Session and Flask-Login), and then redirect the user again to the URL they originally started the login process from. The final redirect is based on the `state` parameter passed to the `/sso/login` endpoint. So the flow is kind of like this:

`/app/home/login` > `/api/sso/login?state=/app/home` > `accounts.google.com/auth` > `/api/sso/auth` > `/app/home`

Now, the flow works just fine when calling the API directly, the final redirect is then pointed to the `/api/user/info`, which correctly shows the details of the currently logged in user. The flow works as well when calling the API from the frontend app when both services run bare-bones from the local machine (so, for the API - simple `flask run` from the terminal, for the app - `yarn start`). The problem starts when I want to run the setup in docker containers - that's the setup used in deployment, running on AWS infrastructure. After running two containers (not using docker-compose) every call to the API from the frontend app gets a new session ID, and in result - new session. This is obviously a problem, since the session is crucial for correctly authenticating the user. The outcome is that after clicking the "Log in" button, getting redirected to the Google SSO, the user gets a 401 from the `api/sso/auth` endpoint, because it fails the `state` sanity check:

```py
class SSOLogin(Resource):
    @staticmethod
    def get():
        req_state = request.args.get("state"):

        session[AUTH_STATE_KEY] = state  # first call - the endpoint saves the state to the session
        session.permanent = True

        return redirect(uri)
...
class SSOAuth(Resource):
    @staticmethod
    def get():
        req_state = request.args.get("state")
        session_state = session.get(AUTH_STATE_KEY)  # to check if the state is the same as the one returned from Google SSO

        if req_state != session_state:  # False every time, because the session ID changes between the calls and the session_state is always None
            return {
                "error": "Invalid state parameter"
            }, 401
...
```

I looked for the answer, of course, but nothing helped. The session is file-based, but I tried using redis with the exact same result. I tried configuring the session config in many ways, tried configuring the CORS extension as well - nothing helps. The session secret key is passed through the environment variable, not randomly generated. I can try using docker-compose, but it's not preferred, since it won't be used on the deployment environment. I'm baffled, guys.

Comment: i'm not sure about this, but i might had the same problem last year. I think I've solved it with sending the auth data via a cookie. In my case I've used JWT tokens.

Comment: hey, flask-session is using cookies to store the session id on client-side, that's why it cannot retrieve the data when the id changes for every call. I was considering switching to JWT, but I would prefer not to.

Comment: can you then store the session cookie from flask on the client and send it with every request?